# How to get an element of a FieldSet

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a FieldSet :

```
Ext.define('admin.view.BuzzEditForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    requires: ['Ext.form.FieldSet','Ext.Img'],
    id: 'editorPanel',
    xtype: 'buzzEditForm',
    config: {
        /* modal: true,
         hideOnMaskTap: false,
         centered: true,
         width: 500,
         scrollable: false,*/
        items: [{
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'keyword',
                    label: 'Mots clés'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'title',
                    label: 'Titre'
                },
                {
                    id: 'editorPanelvisual',
                    xtype: 'field',
                    label: 'Visuel actuel',
                    component:
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        layout: 'hbox',
                        items: [
                            {
                                id: 'buzzImageField',
                                flex: 1,
                                xtype: 'image',
                                src: 'http://pierre.chachatelier.fr/programmation/images/mozodojo-original-image.jpg',
                                height: 200
                            },
                            {
                                id: 'buzzChooseImageField',
                                xtype: 'button',
                                iconCls: 'arrow_right',
                                iconMask: true,
                                ui: 'action',
                                action: 'chooseBuzzImage'
                            }

                        ]
                    }

                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'visual',
                    label: 'Visuel'
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
});
```

I can get my formPanel using Ext.getCmp('#editorPanel') but how can i get a field using its name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `Ext.ComponentQuery`, for example:

`Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[name="keyword"]')`

For further details, please see this: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery

Comment: Thank you, you helped me so much today :) I am starting with sencha touch, so i have a lot of questions.

Comment: You're so welcome. I'm quite busy these days but hopefully can help all of you at my best. :)

Comment: You make a mistake in your syntax, it's : Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[name="keyword"]')

Comment: my bad, thank you for your remind, I will update it right then

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention that `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[name="keyword"]')` returns an array. So if you need only one element like the example above, you will have to use .pop() function to get the last and the only element and then manipulate with it.